# an array for returning int in C programming

Tags: arrays, c, return

I have a question about return an array from a function in C, I do not know why it keeps giving the result as a code dumped. Please help, I really really thank you!
I set up an int list3[size3] but it seems like I have to return with a format of an array as int*list3. So I set up another array as list4[size3] to copy list3 into list4. But I am not sure it is a reason it cause code dumped. If it is, please help me with the advice to solve the problem. Thank you so much again!.

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int* merged(int[], int[], int, int);
void sort(int[], int);

int main() {

    int size1;
    printf("Enter list1: ");
    scanf("%d", &size1);

    int list1[size1];

    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &list1[i]);
    }

    int size2;
    printf("Enter list2: ");
    scanf("%d", &size2);

    int list2[size2];

    for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &list2[i]);
    }

    int* list3 = merged(list1, list2, size1, size2);

    printf("The merged list is: ");

    int size3 = size1 + size2;

    for (int i = 0; i < size3; i++) {
        printf("%d ", list3[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int* merged(int list1[], int list2[], int size1, int size2) {
    int list3[size1 + size2];
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        list3[i] = list1[i];
    }

    int count = size1;

    for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
        list3[count] = list2[i];
        count++;
    }

    int size3 = size1 + size2;

    sort(list3, size3);

    int* list4;

    for (int i = 0; i < size3; i++) {
        list4[i] = list3[i];
    }

    return list3;
}

void sort(int list3[], int size3) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size3; i++) {
        int min = list3[i];
        int min_index = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < size3; j++) {
            if (list3[j] < min) {
                min = list3[j];
                min_index = j;
            }
        }

        if (min_index != i) {
            list3[min_index] = list3[i];
            list3[i] = min;
        }
    }
}
```

https://onlinegdb.com/-ChT7PA3w

Comment: Have you tried inspecting it using something like gdb and find what line and element is giving you the seg fault? Also, indenting your code better would help its readability

Comment: You cannot return a pointer to an automatic variable (such as `list3`). You cannot use a pointer variable which has not been initialized to point to some object (`list4`). If you want a function to return an array, you basically have two options: dynamically allocate the array with `malloc` or create the array in the caller and supply it as an additional parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You `merge` return pointer to the local array. It is UB as this array stops existing when the function returns. So the returned pointer references an invalid object.

```
int *merged(const int * restrict list1, const int * restrict  list2, size_t size1, size_t size2) 
{
    int *result = NULL;
    int l1size = size1 * !!list1, l2size = size2 * !!list2;
    size_t newsize = l1size + l2size;

    if(newsize)
    {
        result = malloc(newsize * sizeof(*result));
        if(result)
        {
            if(l1size) memcpy(result, list1, l1size * sizeof(*result));
            if(l2size) memcpy(result + l1size, list2, l2size * sizeof(*result));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

void printList(const int * restrict list, size_t size)
{
    if(size && list)
    {
        for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++)
            printf("[%2zu] = %3d\n", index, list[index]);
    }
}

void initList(int * restrict list, size_t size, int maxval)
{
    if(size && list)
    {
        for(size_t index = 0; index < size; index++)
            list[index] = rand() % maxval;
    }
}


int main() {

    size_t size1 = 20;
    size_t size2 = 10;
    int list1[size1], list2[size2];

    initList(list1, size1, 100);
    initList(list2, size2, 100);
    printList(list1, size1);
    printf("----------------\n");
    printList(list2, size2);
    printf("----------------\n");
    
    int *list3 = merged(list1, list2, size1, size2);
    printList(list3, size2 + size1);
    printf("----------------\n");

    free(list3);
}
```

Also use the correct type for sizes `size_t`

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems in your code:

First:
You are returning `list3` from `merged()` function. `list3` is a local(automatic) non-static variable and its lifetime is limited to its scope i.e. the block in which it has been declared. Any attempt to access it outside of its lifetime lead to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Also, `list3` is VLA (Variable Length Array), you cannot declare it `static` as VLA cannot have `static` storage duration. Other option is to declare `list3` as pointer to `int` and allocate memory dynamically to it.

Second:
In the `merged()`, you are dereferencing uninitialised pointer `list4`. Dereferencing an uninitialised pointer is undefined behaviour. Allocate memory to `list4` and then use it. Moreover, why you need `list4`? You copy the `list1` and `list2` to `list3` and returning `list3` from `merged()` function. I do not see any use of `list4`. Better to remove it from `merged()` function.

So, only one change is required in `merged()` in your code:

```
int*merged(int list1[], int list2[], int size1, int size2) {
    int * list3 = malloc ((size1 + size2) * sizeof (int));
    if (list3 == NULL) {
        //handle the allocation failure
        //I am exiting..
        printf ("Failed to allocate memory\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    ....
    ....
    ....
    sort (list3, size3);
    // removed list4 from code

    return list3;
}
```

Make sure to free the dynamically allocated memory. In the `main()` function, you should do:

```
int main (void) {
    ....
    ....
    ....
    for (int i = 0; i < size3; i++) {
        printf("%d ", list3[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    // free dynamically allocated memory
    free (list3);

    return 0;
}
```

Couple of points, which I am leaving it up to you to learn and implement:

- There is one serious problem in your code that you not validating the user input. Try giving value of `size1` and `size2` as `0` or negative value or very big positive value and check what happens.  Handle the user input appropriately. Also, think over, if you really need VLA (Variable Length Array) or you can use fixed size array. A fixed size array can be static.
- There is scope of improvement in implementation part. Try to find out them and make improvements.

Comment: It may be better form to _not_ have `merged` allocate the memory for the merged list. If we take this responsibility away from `merged` then the memory can be automatically allocated in `main` and a pointer to it passed to `merged`. Merged having a declaration more like: `int * merged(int * dest, int * list1, int * list1, size_t size1, size_t size2)`

Comment: @Chris In C, It is perfectly normal for a function to allocate memory and return the reference of that memory and that's what `merged()` function is doing - returning a new list which is merge+sort of 2 list passed as argument to it. Beside this, read the last point of my post, I have clearly mentioned that _There is scope of improvement in the implementation part_ and I left it on OP to identify it and make the respective changes in his code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `return list3` in `merged`, as you are returning the address of the first element (not the array), but the whole `list3` array is out of scope and lifetime once the function returns, so it is no longer available (and the pointer is pointing to a place that is no longer valid for that purpose)  You need to allocate memory dynamically to allow the array to survive the function call, or use a global variable (which makes the function non-reentrant)